# Form appears outside a parent Tabsheet in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I wrote the below code in Delphi 10:

```
FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm := TExportWizardFolderSelection.Create(nil);  
FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.Parent := tabSheetFolderSelection;
FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.Align := alClient;  
FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;  
FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.Visible := False;
```

This code works in Delphi 2006, but in Delphi 10 the Form appears outside of the Tabsheet.  Without changing the code, it works differently in both versions.

What modification/additional code is required to run this Form correctly in Delphi 10?

[image]

Comment: Why are you embedding a `TForm` in a `TTabSheet` at all? You should be using a `TFrame` instead. Your screenshot looks like a `TFrame` that has been made a child to the wrong `Parent`.

Comment: Debugging 101 : Does tabSheetFolderSelection contains the same value in D2006 and Delphi10 when it is assigned to FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.Parent? (is it <> nil?)

Comment: What code i write to set form in Tabsheet. currently it go outside from tabsheet control in delphi xe 10.1

Comment: delphi 10.1 berlin

Comment: What code i write to display form with in Tabsheet. currently it go outside from tabsheet control in delphi 10.1 berlin

Comment: how to set form position within Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable explanation is that you assign `nil` as the `Parent` of the form. Presumably because `tabSheetFolderSelection` is `nil`.

Do some debugging first of all to confirm that hypothesis. Then you need to inspect the rest of you code to understand why `tabSheetFolderSelection` is `nil`.

Comment: tabSheetFolderSelection is not nil.it contain data

Comment: Seems kind of implausible, at least given the code in the question. Probably the explanation is to be found in other code, code that only you can see. This is why, and oh my I am finally getting a little blue in the face, you need to make a [mcve].

Comment: tabSheetFolderSelection  cantain FAnchorRules = (x:402,y:202) and Forignalparentsize = (x:410,y:233) but after assingment to form FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm.Parent := tabSheetFolderSelection; form FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm show (x:0,y:0) for both and rest are same. i think because of this form go outside from tabsheet.

Answer (score -3):

Set BorderStyle Property := bsSingle for FExportWizardFolderSelectionForm form in design mode